# How to import SSL certificates into OpenSSL

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl

I have server certificates for making SSL connection. So, whenever I execute

```
openssl s_client -engine gost -CApath /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ -connect lk.egrz.ru:443 -servername lk.egrz.ru
```

I get

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : GOST2001-GOST89-GOST89
    Session-ID: 50AA2B055BC60403A82DBADAD8056656CB67BE639E4CC9CE605A020DE387A056
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: DC3812BFD75154DB7C5D0D456E5B5719E7733BF48CB2344186AD17B0166560A153CA5C9B3E3E1FBF4C453DD3114B561F
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1576144768
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

I believe that the error `21 (unable to verify the first certificate)` means that I have no trusted cerificates on the client side.

The question is how do I import those into trusted certificates. Just like adding them in `cacerts` in Java.

Unfortunately, in all the tutorials the private key is specified. This is just a server certificate, I don't have it, obviously. Does mentioning `-CApath`  in executing the command above add all the certs inside trusted?

If not, how do I specify all the certificates which the client trusts?

Thanks in advance

**UPD**

Here's my log with `-debug` enabled (command `openssl s_client -engine gost -CApath /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ -connect lk.egrz.ru:443 -servername lk.egrz.ru -debug`):

```
engine "gost" set.
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72efd370] (322 bytes => 322 (0x142))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 3d 01 00 01-39 03 03 bc 22 4a 5e 5b   ....=...9..."J^[
0010 - 7d 8f 2b eb 4c 88 3f 22-87 fc a8 fc c2 03 e3 1c   }.+.L.?"........
0020 - c8 39 46 a8 a0 c0 b1 77-c9 52 37 20 78 50 bf cd   .9F....w.R7 xP..
0030 - 5a 97 dd 35 5a 56 af 40-fd 4f e8 db 57 b4 89 7d   Z..5ZV.@.O..W..}
0040 - cc 90 0d 34 3f 4d 92 5d-7c 43 da 6b 00 42 13 02   ...4?M.]|C.k.B..
0050 - 13 03 13 01 c0 2c c0 30-00 9f cc a9 cc a8 cc aa   .....,.0........
0060 - c0 2b c0 2f 00 9e c0 24-c0 28 00 6b c0 23 c0 27   .+./...$.(.k.#.'
0070 - 00 67 c0 0a c0 14 00 39-c0 09 c0 13 00 33 00 9d   .g.....9.....3..
0080 - 00 9c 00 3d 00 3c ff 85-00 81 00 35 00 2f 00 ff   ...=.<.....5./..
0090 - 01 00 00 ae 00 00 00 0f-00 0d 00 00 0a 6c 6b 2e   .............lk.
00a0 - 65 67 72 7a 2e 72 75 00-0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00   egrz.ru.........
00b0 - 0a 00 0c 00 0a 00 1d 00-17 00 1e 00 19 00 18 00   ................
00c0 - 23 00 00 00 16 00 00 00-17 00 00 00 0d 00 36 00   #.............6.
00d0 - 34 04 03 05 03 06 03 08-07 08 08 08 09 08 0a 08   4...............
00e0 - 0b 08 04 08 05 08 06 04-01 05 01 06 01 03 03 02   ................
00f0 - 03 03 01 02 01 03 02 02-02 04 02 05 02 06 02 ee   ................
0100 - ee ef ef ed ed 00 2b 00-09 08 03 04 03 03 03 02   ......+.........
0110 - 03 01 00 2d 00 02 01 01-00 33 00 26 00 24 00 1d   ...-.....3.&.$..
0120 - 00 20 70 a3 71 dc 54 bc-fb 24 04 94 b6 e6 b0 d2   . p.q.T..$......
0130 - 69 e9 e3 8a 29 9a 4c cb-7b d0 27 53 bc 02 7e 3b   i...).L.{.'S..~;
0140 - 8b 5c                                             .\
read from 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72ef4093] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 55                                    ....U
read from 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72ef4098] (85 bytes => 85 (0x55))
0000 - 02 00 00 51 03 01 21 f9-b6 2b 38 ce 63 6b 19 8f   ...Q..!..+8.ck..
0010 - ff 52 58 ef 72 42 76 e0-aa 40 fe 69 9b ed b5 63   .RX.rBv..@.i...c
0020 - 33 3a 6e ca 0b 29 20 e9-ee 0a 42 26 2a d6 44 2b   3:n..) ...B&*.D+
0030 - d6 d4 38 dc d9 70 bc 79-bd bf 3b 20 c4 05 56 b1   ..8..p.y..; ..V.
0040 - e4 53 41 92 c3 41 3b 00-81 00 00 09 00 00 00 00   .SA..A;.........
0050 - ff 01 00 01 00                                    .....
read from 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72ef4093] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 01 07 83                                    .....
read from 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72ef4098] (1923 bytes => 1923 (0x783))
0000 - 0b 00 07 7f 00 07 7c 00-07 79 30 82 07 75 30 82   ......|..y0..u0.
0010 - 07 24 a0 03 02 01 02 02-10 41 db 1c 01 51 a8 c8   .$.......A...Q..
0020 - 95 4f e0 cd 89 db ad 1c-0d 30 08 06 06 2a 85 03   .O.......0...*..
0030 - 02 02 03 30 82 01 62 31-25 30 23 06 09 2a 86 48   ...0..b1%0#..*.H
0040 - 86 f7 0d 01 09 01 16 16-53 75 70 70 6f 72 74 49   ........SupportI
0050 - 49 54 40 69 6e 66 6f 74-65 63 73 2e 72 75 31 61   IT@infotecs.ru1a
0060 - 30 5f 06 03 55 04 09 0c-58 d0 a1 d1 82 d0 b0 d1   0_..U...X.......
0070 - 80 d1 8b d0 b9 20 d0 9f-d0 b5 d1 82 d1 80 d0 be   ..... ..........
0080 - d0 b2 d1 81 d0 ba d0 be-2d d0 a0 d0 b0 d0 b7 d1   ........-.......
0090 - 83 d0 bc d0 be d0 b2 d1-81 d0 ba d0 b8 d0 b9 20   ............... 
00a0 - d0 bf d1 80 d0 be d0 b5-d0 b7 d0 b4 2c 20 d0 b4   ............, ..
00b0 - 2e 20 31 2f 32 33 2c 20-d1 81 d1 82 d1 80 2e 20   . 1/23, ....... 
00c0 - 31 31 18 30 16 06 05 2a-85 03 64 01 12 0d 31 30   11.0...*..d...10
00d0 - 32 37 37 33 39 31 31 33-30 34 39 31 1a 30 18 06   277391130491.0..
00e0 - 08 2a 85 03 03 81 03 01-01 12 0c 30 30 37 37 34   .*.........00774
00f0 - 33 30 32 30 35 36 30 31-0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06   30205601.0...U..
0100 - 13 02 52 55 31 1c 30 1a-06 03 55 04 08 0c 13 37   ..RU1.0...U....7
0110 - 37 20 d0 b3 2e 20 d0 9c-d0 be d1 81 d0 ba d0 b2   7 ... ..........
0120 - d0 b0 31 15 30 13 06 03-55 04 07 0c 0c d0 9c d0   ..1.0...U.......
0130 - be d1 81 d0 ba d0 b2 d0-b0 31 40 30 3e 06 03 55   .........1@0>..U
0140 - 04 0a 0c 37 d0 9e d0 90-d0 9e 20 c2 ab d0 98 d0   ...7...... .....
0150 - bd d1 84 d0 be d0 a2 d0-b5 d0 9a d0 a1 20 d0 98   ............. ..
0160 - d0 bd d1 82 d0 b5 d1 80-d0 bd d0 b5 d1 82 20 d0   .............. .
0170 - a2 d1 80 d0 b0 d1 81 d1-82 c2 bb 31 1c 30 1a 06   ...........1.0..
0180 - 03 55 04 03 0c 13 d0 a3-d0 a6 20 d0 98 d0 98 d0   .U........ .....
0190 - a2 20 28 d0 9d d0 9a 31-29 30 1e 17 0d 31 37 31   . (....1)0...171
01a0 - 32 32 32 31 34 30 37 30-37 5a 17 0d 32 33 31 32   222140707Z..2312
01b0 - 32 32 31 34 32 37 30 37-5a 30 82 01 24 31 1a 30   22142707Z0..$1.0
01c0 - 18 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7-0d 01 09 01 16 0b 69 6e   ...*.H........in
01d0 - 66 6f 40 67 67 65 2e 72-75 31 1a 30 18 06 08 2a   fo@gge.ru1.0...*
01e0 - 85 03 03 81 03 01 01 12-0c 30 30 37 37 30 37 30   .........0077070
01f0 - 38 32 30 37 31 31 18 30-16 06 05 2a 85 03 64 01   820711.0...*..d.
0200 - 12 0d 31 30 32 37 37 30-30 31 33 33 39 31 31 31   ..10277001339111
0210 - 36 30 34 06 03 55 04 0b-0c 2d d0 a3 d0 bf d1 80   604..U...-......
0220 - d0 b0 d0 b2 d0 bb d0 b5-d0 bd d0 b8 d0 b5 20 d0   .............. .
0230 - b1 d0 b5 d0 b7 d0 be d0-bf d0 b0 d1 81 d0 bd d0   ................
0240 - be d1 81 d1 82 d0 b8 31-41 30 3f 06 03 55 04 0a   .......1A0?..U..
0250 - 0c 38 d0 a4 d0 90 d0 a3-20 22 d0 93 d0 9b d0 90   .8...... "......
0260 - d0 92 d0 93 d0 9e d0 a1-d0 ad d0 9a d0 a1 d0 9f   ................
0270 - d0 95 d0 a0 d0 a2 d0 98-d0 97 d0 90 20 d0 a0 d0   ............ ...
0280 - 9e d0 a1 d0 a1 d0 98 d0-98 22 31 15 30 13 06 03   ........."1.0...
0290 - 55 04 07 0c 0c d0 9c d0-be d1 81 d0 ba d0 b2 d0   U...............
02a0 - b0 31 1c 30 1a 06 03 55-04 08 0c 13 37 37 20 d0   .1.0...U....77 .
02b0 - b3 2e 20 d0 9c d0 be d1-81 d0 ba d0 b2 d0 b0 31   .. ............1
02c0 - 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06-13 02 52 55 31 13 30 11   .0...U....RU1.0.
02d0 - 06 03 55 04 03 13 0a 6c-6b 2e 65 67 72 7a 2e 72   ..U....lk.egrz.r
02e0 - 75 30 63 30 1c 06 06 2a-85 03 02 02 13 30 12 06   u0c0...*.....0..
02f0 - 07 2a 85 03 02 02 24 00-06 07 2a 85 03 02 02 1e   .*....$...*.....
0300 - 01 03 43 00 04 40 76 f2-38 08 af 42 6c ab 0f 06   ..C..@v.8..Bl...
0310 - 8c 6e 69 2d e1 95 41 cf-b1 3c 04 a8 3d 00 9b 4c   .ni-..A..<..=..L
0320 - 96 e8 2f 64 6f db ad 9f-ac 3e 78 02 4d 7f 14 13   ../do....>x.M...
0330 - 51 05 37 bd b9 42 12 11-64 2f f8 22 83 e2 8b 61   Q.7..B..d/."...a
0340 - 3b 25 27 a6 41 cc a3 82-03 ec 30 82 03 e8 30 1d   ;%'.A.....0...0.
0350 - 06 03 55 1d 0e 04 16 04-14 59 61 59 81 20 ef a4   ..U......YaY. ..
0360 - 5d 11 57 8f 63 5c e3 91-18 c0 c5 8e 7d 30 2b 06   ].W.c\......}0+.
0370 - 03 55 1d 10 04 24 30 22-80 0f 32 30 31 37 31 32   .U...$0"..201712
0380 - 32 32 31 34 31 37 30 37-5a 81 0f 32 30 32 30 31   22141707Z..20201
0390 - 32 32 32 31 34 30 37 30-37 5a 30 13 06 03 55 1d   222140707Z0...U.
03a0 - 25 04 0c 30 0a 06 08 2b-06 01 05 05 07 03 01 30   %..0...+.......0
03b0 - 0e 06 03 55 1d 0f 01 01-ff 04 04 03 02 04 f0 30   ...U...........0
03c0 - 71 06 03 55 1d 1f 04 6a-30 68 30 32 a0 30 a0 2e   q..U...j0h02.0..
03d0 - 86 2c 68 74 74 70 3a 2f-2f 75 63 31 2e 69 69 74   .,http://uc1.iit
03e0 - 72 75 73 74 2e 72 75 2f-75 63 2f 43 41 2d 49 49   rust.ru/uc/CA-II
03f0 - 54 2d 4e 4b 31 2d 32 30-31 36 2e 63 72 6c 30 32   T-NK1-2016.crl02
0400 - a0 30 a0 2e 86 2c 68 74-74 70 3a 2f 2f 75 63 32   .0...,http://uc2
0410 - 2e 69 69 74 72 75 73 74-2e 72 75 2f 75 63 2f 43   .iitrust.ru/uc/C
0420 - 41 2d 49 49 54 2d 4e 4b-31 2d 32 30 31 36 2e 63   A-IIT-NK1-2016.c
0430 - 72 6c 30 82 01 a3 06 03-55 1d 23 04 82 01 9a 30   rl0.....U.#....0
0440 - 82 01 96 80 14 08 7d c7-96 fa 36 fd 2d 7e e4 47   ......}...6.-~.G
0450 - 60 e2 8d 84 7e 47 35 3b-62 a1 82 01 6a a4 82 01   `...~G5;b...j...
0460 - 66 30 82 01 62 31 25 30-23 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7   f0..b1%0#..*.H..
0470 - 0d 01 09 01 16 16 53 75-70 70 6f 72 74 49 49 54   ......SupportIIT
0480 - 40 69 6e 66 6f 74 65 63-73 2e 72 75 31 61 30 5f   @infotecs.ru1a0_
0490 - 06 03 55 04 09 0c 58 d0-a1 d1 82 d0 b0 d1 80 d1   ..U...X.........
04a0 - 8b d0 b9 20 d0 9f d0 b5-d1 82 d1 80 d0 be d0 b2   ... ............
04b0 - d1 81 d0 ba d0 be 2d d0-a0 d0 b0 d0 b7 d1 83 d0   ......-.........
04c0 - bc d0 be d0 b2 d1 81 d0-ba d0 b8 d0 b9 20 d0 bf   ............. ..
04d0 - d1 80 d0 be d0 b5 d0 b7-d0 b4 2c 20 d0 b4 2e 20   .........., ... 
04e0 - 31 2f 32 33 2c 20 d1 81-d1 82 d1 80 2e 20 31 31   1/23, ....... 11
04f0 - 18 30 16 06 05 2a 85 03-64 01 12 0d 31 30 32 37   .0...*..d...1027
0500 - 37 33 39 31 31 33 30 34-39 31 1a 30 18 06 08 2a   7391130491.0...*
0510 - 85 03 03 81 03 01 01 12-0c 30 30 37 37 34 33 30   .........0077430
0520 - 32 30 35 36 30 31 0b 30-09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02   205601.0...U....
0530 - 52 55 31 1c 30 1a 06 03-55 04 08 0c 13 37 37 20   RU1.0...U....77 
0540 - d0 b3 2e 20 d0 9c d0 be-d1 81 d0 ba d0 b2 d0 b0   ... ............
0550 - 31 15 30 13 06 03 55 04-07 0c 0c d0 9c d0 be d1   1.0...U.........
0560 - 81 d0 ba d0 b2 d0 b0 31-40 30 3e 06 03 55 04 0a   .......1@0>..U..
0570 - 0c 37 d0 9e d0 90 d0 9e-20 c2 ab d0 98 d0 bd d1   .7...... .......
0580 - 84 d0 be d0 a2 d0 b5 d0-9a d0 a1 20 d0 98 d0 bd   ........... ....
0590 - d1 82 d0 b5 d1 80 d0 bd-d0 b5 d1 82 20 d0 a2 d1   ............ ...
05a0 - 80 d0 b0 d1 81 d1 82 c2-bb 31 1c 30 1a 06 03 55   .........1.0...U
05b0 - 04 03 0c 13 d0 a3 d0 a6-20 d0 98 d0 98 d0 a2 20   ........ ...... 
05c0 - 28 d0 9d d0 9a 31 29 82-10 d1 c8 13 01 67 a6 06   (....1)......g..
05d0 - a4 4e f5 77 58 a8 da 79-53 30 48 06 08 2b 06 01   .N.wX..yS0H..+..
05e0 - 05 05 07 01 01 04 3c 30-3a 30 38 06 08 2b 06 01   ......<0:08..+..
05f0 - 05 05 07 30 02 86 2c 68-74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 75 63   ...0..,http://uc
0600 - 31 2e 69 69 74 72 75 73-74 2e 72 75 2f 75 63 2f   1.iitrust.ru/uc/
0610 - 43 41 2d 49 49 54 2d 4e-4b 31 2d 32 30 31 36 2e   CA-IIT-NK1-2016.
0620 - 63 65 72 30 2f 06 03 55-1d 20 04 28 30 26 30 06   cer0/..U. .(0&0.
0630 - 06 04 55 1d 20 00 30 08-06 06 2a 85 03 64 71 01   ..U. .0...*..dq.
0640 - 30 08 06 06 2a 85 03 64-71 02 30 08 06 06 2a 85   0...*..dq.0...*.
0650 - 03 64 71 03 30 57 06 05-2a 85 03 64 6f 04 4e 0c   .dq.0W..*..do.N.
0660 - 4c d0 9f d1 80 d0 be d0-b3 d1 80 d0 b0 d0 bc d0   L...............
0670 - bc d0 bd d0 be 2d d0 b0-d0 bf d0 bf d0 b0 d1 80   .....-..........
0680 - d0 b0 d1 82 d0 bd d1 8b-d0 b9 20 d0 ba d0 be d0   .......... .....
0690 - bc d0 bf d0 bb d0 b5 d0-ba 63 20 56 69 50 4e 65   .........c ViPNe
06a0 - 74 20 48 53 4d 20 31 20-28 4b 42 32 29 30 81 86   t HSM 1 (KB2)0..
06b0 - 06 05 2a 85 03 64 70 04-7d 30 7b 0c 4c d0 9f d1   ..*..dp.}0{.L...
06c0 - 80 d0 be d0 b3 d1 80 d0-b0 d0 bc d0 bc d0 bd d0   ................
06d0 - be 2d d0 b0 d0 bf d0 bf-d0 b0 d1 80 d0 b0 d1 82   .-..............
06e0 - d0 bd d1 8b d0 b9 20 d0-ba d0 be d0 bc d0 bf d0   ...... .........
06f0 - bb d0 b5 d0 ba 63 20 56-69 50 4e 65 74 20 48 53   .....c ViPNet HS
0700 - 4d 20 31 20 28 4b 42 32-29 0c 25 d0 9f d0 9a 20   M 1 (KB2).%.... 
0710 - 22 56 69 50 4e 65 74 20-43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63   "ViPNet Certific
0720 - 61 74 69 6f 6e 20 41 75-74 68 6f 72 69 74 79 22   ation Authority"
0730 - 0c 01 2d 0c 01 2d 30 08-06 06 2a 85 03 02 02 03   ..-..-0...*.....
0740 - 03 41 00 bb ec 5e 14 df-d9 68 35 9d 2a 6e c7 03   .A...^...h5.*n..
0750 - e0 e7 da 45 13 0a 09 cd-23 76 6a a9 89 bc 94 01   ...E....#vj.....
0760 - ef 2b b3 c1 e5 ab 5b 17-90 c5 6a cc 8e 59 03 26   .+....[...j..Y.&
0770 - 8f 62 1e 83 20 28 5f 79-05 e2 2f f9 2b cc 27 12   .b.. (_y../.+.'.
0780 - da 6e 25                                          .n%
depth=0 emailAddress = info@gge.ru, INN = 007707082071, OGRN = 1027700133911, OU = \D0\A3\D0\BF\D1\80\D0\B0\D0\B2\D0\BB\D0\B5\D0\BD\D0\B8\D0\B5 \D0\B1\D0\B5\D0\B7\D0\BE\D0\BF\D0\B0\D1\81\D0\BD\D0\BE\D1\81\D1\82\D0\B8, O = \D0\A4\D0\90\D0\A3 \"\D0\93\D0\9B\D0\90\D0\92\D0\93\D0\9E\D0\A1\D0\AD\D0\9A\D0\A1\D0\9F\D0\95\D0\A0\D0\A2\D0\98\D0\97\D0\90 \D0\A0\D0\9E\D0\A1\D0\A1\D0\98\D0\98\", L = \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, ST = 77 \D0\B3. \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, C = RU, CN = lk.egrz.ru
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 emailAddress = info@gge.ru, INN = 007707082071, OGRN = 1027700133911, OU = \D0\A3\D0\BF\D1\80\D0\B0\D0\B2\D0\BB\D0\B5\D0\BD\D0\B8\D0\B5 \D0\B1\D0\B5\D0\B7\D0\BE\D0\BF\D0\B0\D1\81\D0\BD\D0\BE\D1\81\D1\82\D0\B8, O = \D0\A4\D0\90\D0\A3 \"\D0\93\D0\9B\D0\90\D0\92\D0\93\D0\9E\D0\A1\D0\AD\D0\9A\D0\A1\D0\9F\D0\95\D0\A0\D0\A2\D0\98\D0\97\D0\90 \D0\A0\D0\9E\D0\A1\D0\A1\D0\98\D0\98\", L = \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, ST = 77 \D0\B3. \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, C = RU, CN = lk.egrz.ru
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
read from 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72ef4093] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 04                                    .....
read from 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72ef4098] (4 bytes => 4 (0x4))
0000 - 0e 00 00 00                                       ....
write to 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72efd370] (210 bytes => 210 (0xD2))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 ae 10 00 00-aa 30 81 a7 30 81 a4 30   .........0..0..0
0010 - 28 04 20 81 a7 c0 d3 41-2f 18 96 af d4 bd 26 42   (. ....A/.....&B
0020 - 88 0e fe 83 8f d1 50 35-f6 c1 cb 67 b7 3b 5c e6   ......P5...g.;\.
0030 - 5b 45 90 04 04 f0 f6 bb-47 a0 78 06 07 2a 85 03   [E......G.x..*..
0040 - 02 02 1f 01 a0 63 30 1c-06 06 2a 85 03 02 02 13   .....c0...*.....
0050 - 30 12 06 07 2a 85 03 02-02 24 00 06 07 2a 85 03   0...*....$...*..
0060 - 02 02 1e 01 03 43 00 04-40 1d e9 1e cd 1a 84 12   .....C..@.......
0070 - 2c 00 38 39 bb cc 31 e9-d5 4c 9d 58 d6 fc 35 23   ,.89..1..L.X..5#
0080 - ba f4 0a 8d ce f2 42 7d-7b d0 b2 76 61 90 ac 9c   ......B}{..va...
0090 - 42 4c 4f a3 d7 53 96 9c-38 12 80 d1 1c 07 28 88   BLO..S..8.....(.
00a0 - ab f6 84 9c 14 21 70 92-8a 04 08 5f 2e e3 06 68   .....!p...._...h
00b0 - e3 01 fa 14 03 01 00 01-01 16 03 01 00 14 bc 01   ................
00c0 - b2 b4 d2 d0 f6 da c0 d2-f7 90 3d 96 f3 00 60 06   ..........=...`.
00d0 - 43 6f                                             Co
read from 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72ef4093] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 14 03 01 00 01                                    .....
read from 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72ef4098] (1 bytes => 1 (0x1))
0000 - 01                                                .
read from 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72ef4093] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 14                                    .....
read from 0x557b72eec7b0 [0x557b72ef4098] (20 bytes => 20 (0x14))
0000 - 93 b4 4c cd ea c3 44 89-de b5 57 08 1f 51 88 16   ..L...D...W..Q..
0010 - 56 ce 7d b3                                       V.}.
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:emailAddress = info@gge.ru, INN = 007707082071, OGRN = 1027700133911, OU = \D0\A3\D0\BF\D1\80\D0\B0\D0\B2\D0\BB\D0\B5\D0\BD\D0\B8\D0\B5 \D0\B1\D0\B5\D0\B7\D0\BE\D0\BF\D0\B0\D1\81\D0\BD\D0\BE\D1\81\D1\82\D0\B8, O = \D0\A4\D0\90\D0\A3 \"\D0\93\D0\9B\D0\90\D0\92\D0\93\D0\9E\D0\A1\D0\AD\D0\9A\D0\A1\D0\9F\D0\95\D0\A0\D0\A2\D0\98\D0\97\D0\90 \D0\A0\D0\9E\D0\A1\D0\A1\D0\98\D0\98\", L = \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, ST = 77 \D0\B3. \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, C = RU, CN = lk.egrz.ru
   i:emailAddress = SupportIIT@infotecs.ru, street = "\D0\A1\D1\82\D0\B0\D1\80\D1\8B\D0\B9 \D0\9F\D0\B5\D1\82\D1\80\D0\BE\D0\B2\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\BE-\D0\A0\D0\B0\D0\B7\D1\83\D0\BC\D0\BE\D0\B2\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B8\D0\B9 \D0\BF\D1\80\D0\BE\D0\B5\D0\B7\D0\B4, \D0\B4. 1/23, \D1\81\D1\82\D1\80. 1", OGRN = 1027739113049, INN = 007743020560, C = RU, ST = 77 \D0\B3. \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, L = \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, O = \D0\9E\D0\90\D0\9E \C2\AB\D0\98\D0\BD\D1\84\D0\BE\D0\A2\D0\B5\D0\9A\D0\A1 \D0\98\D0\BD\D1\82\D0\B5\D1\80\D0\BD\D0\B5\D1\82 \D0\A2\D1\80\D0\B0\D1\81\D1\82\C2\BB, CN = \D0\A3\D0\A6 \D0\98\D0\98\D0\A2 (\D0\9D\D0\9A1)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=emailAddress = info@gge.ru, INN = 007707082071, OGRN = 1027700133911, OU = \D0\A3\D0\BF\D1\80\D0\B0\D0\B2\D0\BB\D0\B5\D0\BD\D0\B8\D0\B5 \D0\B1\D0\B5\D0\B7\D0\BE\D0\BF\D0\B0\D1\81\D0\BD\D0\BE\D1\81\D1\82\D0\B8, O = \D0\A4\D0\90\D0\A3 \"\D0\93\D0\9B\D0\90\D0\92\D0\93\D0\9E\D0\A1\D0\AD\D0\9A\D0\A1\D0\9F\D0\95\D0\A0\D0\A2\D0\98\D0\97\D0\90 \D0\A0\D0\9E\D0\A1\D0\A1\D0\98\D0\98\", L = \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, ST = 77 \D0\B3. \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, C = RU, CN = lk.egrz.ru

issuer=emailAddress = SupportIIT@infotecs.ru, street = "\D0\A1\D1\82\D0\B0\D1\80\D1\8B\D0\B9 \D0\9F\D0\B5\D1\82\D1\80\D0\BE\D0\B2\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\BE-\D0\A0\D0\B0\D0\B7\D1\83\D0\BC\D0\BE\D0\B2\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B8\D0\B9 \D0\BF\D1\80\D0\BE\D0\B5\D0\B7\D0\B4, \D0\B4. 1/23, \D1\81\D1\82\D1\80. 1", OGRN = 1027739113049, INN = 007743020560, C = RU, ST = 77 \D0\B3. \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, L = \D0\9C\D0\BE\D1\81\D0\BA\D0\B2\D0\B0, O = \D0\9E\D0\90\D0\9E \C2\AB\D0\98\D0\BD\D1\84\D0\BE\D0\A2\D0\B5\D0\9A\D0\A1 \D0\98\D0\BD\D1\82\D0\B5\D1\80\D0\BD\D0\B5\D1\82 \D0\A2\D1\80\D0\B0\D1\81\D1\82\C2\BB, CN = \D0\A3\D0\A6 \D0\98\D0\98\D0\A2 (\D0\9D\D0\9A1)

---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2058 bytes and written 532 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.0, Cipher is GOST2001-GOST89-GOST89
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : GOST2001-GOST89-GOST89
    Session-ID: E9EE0A42262AD6442BD6D438DCD970BC79BDBF3B20C40556B1E4534192C3413B
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: B50D6DE3F1CA679B314AE45BCA335427052177D03B3EF26C100BE588E1942F573A53F35E64DD233A053A198E6EE9A51C
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1576148987
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Comment: Have you tried command with -debug option?  Does it give any information?
I believe you can add CAs on linux with -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  -- Full path may be?

Comment: See this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587851/openssl-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-for-experian-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSL can take CA certificates from a file and or/directory. There are [standard locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138139/how-to-find-out-the-path-for-openssl-trusted-certificate) build into the library but an application can also specify alternative locations. With `s_client` this can be done using the `-CApath directory` and `-CAfile file` arguments.

A certificate file (`-CAfile`) contains a list of CA certificates in PEM format. A certificate directory (`-CApath`) contains the separate files inside a single directory and links to these files based on the subject - see [openssl rehash](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-rehash.html) on how to create the necessary links.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've added these two to my `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`  as base64 certs and now it works like charm. I have only one question left. How to make sure that the connection is ok? I mean send a request and print a response

Comment: `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` Does it mean yet that now I can send HTTP requests and not be let down by SSL?

Comment: Well, I've integrated it with cURL, send a request and it works like charm! Thank you